# How can I achive application failover?

Tags: java, architecture, failover

We have one application(server) running on multiple machines, and each server serves different client. We have a requirement to make the application to be able to failover. That's when one of the application is down for some reason, the other can pick up its work without losing any data.

Any suggestion, materials is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the most appropriate place to do this would be at the network level.  Have the clients connect to some sort of load-balancing proxy which sits in front of your actual app servers, and directs the traffic accordingly.  This load balancer would normally send the clients to different servers as per your question - but when it detects that a server is not responding, it blacklists the failed server and redirects clients to other active servers instead.

Many load balancers offer this sort of failover behaviour - I've done exactly this in the past with [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) but I'm sure that's not the only implementation that will do the job.

---

In terms of commuting state between the servers, that's very difficult.  Failover can be handled in a straightforward way at the network level (as described above) if and only if all of your servers are identical/fungible.  As soon as you start to have server-specific state, it's no longer possible to drop server B in to replace server A, because A and B are not the same.

If you need to deal with this, you'll need to write some sort of logic that has server B notice that server A has gone down, and then somehow salvage the state of A and merge it into its own state.  Hopefully this can be done without conflicts, but this is not guaranteed - the server has to look/act like B to previous B clients, and look/act like A to previous A clients which might in fact be impossible.  And if A didn't shut down cleanly, the state data may be corrupted/out of date.  (And all the while, B has to stop servers C or D from performing this same recovery, and it has to ensure that the load balancer knows it's the new A.)

It is much *much* **much** easier to do failover without local state, where all the servers are effectively just a bunch of CPU cycles, and you store state in client cookies or on some central database.  This way individual machines can be switched in and out transparently, and I would encourage you to pursue this model if at all possible.

Comment: Hi Doyle, Thanks for your reply. since we have some state in the application, when we redirect the new request to new server, we can't get the previous state of this request (this new request might be a follow up request to previous one). Do you know a good way to solve this? in fact, I think what I need is simpler than normal faiover. what I need is: when I tell the first server to shut down, I want it to smoothly move its current work to another server, and the request sent to the first server will be forwarded to this new server.

Comment: That's not simpler, that's a lot more complex.  If the state resides on some central database, then you can pick it up on the new server (assuming you have global keys such as usernames, and not just server-specific session IDs).  If the state resides only within the memory of the old server, then you're pretty much hosed.  What happens in the usual case where the first server *crashes*, instead of being shut down?  If you want failover, you **have** to have global (i.e. non-local), consistent state storage.

Comment: in usual case, when the first server crashes. we will not be albe to serve some of the clients. Currently we don't care about this. Do you know of Hazelcast, seems it's used to handle distributed system. Not sure whether it meets my need.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Hazelcast - it sounds like it *might* do what you need since it "dynamically scales as new servers added", though you'd have to check how well that works in reverse (i.e. dynamically scaling down as servers disappear).